# NAT router with 2 external WAN IPs A+B and multiple internal LANs: Let 1 LAN use external IP address B, all other A

Tags: iptables, routing, nat

I have a simple Linux router with multiple NICs and IPv4 forwarding enabled.

The router has two static WAN IP addresses, assigned to one interface (`eth0`, `eth0:0`). (In the following text, I will obfuscate the actual public IP addresses (257 as an octet).)

The router can be pinged on both external WAN IP addresses from the outside Internet.

Interfaces:

- `eth0`: Internet connection, 134.257.10.**10**/24, gateway 134.257.10.1
- `eth0:0`: Second IP address on that interface: 134.257.10.**20**/24
- `eth1`: LAN 1, 192.168.1.1/24
- `eth2`: LAN 2, 192.168.2.1/24
- `eth3`: LAN 3, 192.168.3.1/24

My setup works and all LAN clients (LAN 1-3) can access the Internet and are externally seen as 134.257.10.**10**. Moreover, I have two incoming port forwardings.

My iptables NAT table looks like this:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# Port forwarding:
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10:80
-A PREROUTING -i eth0:0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.3.33:25
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

How can I have the LAN3 clients (`eth3`) appear as 134.257.10.**20** on the Internet (`eth0:0`) for outgoing connections instead of 134.257.10.**10** (`eth0`)?

Comment: Use `SNAT` and specify the address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use SNAT instead of MASQUERADE

... in order to choose something else than the default.

Instead of using MASQUERADE for the generic case (all other LANs), add a SNAT exception for LAN3 clients. This must match before the other nat/POSTROUTING rule in order to override it so `-I` is used below instead of `-A` to apply at the correct place on the existing ruleset (mind the bogus 257):

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.3.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 134.257.10.20
```

*iptables* (contrary to *nftables*) cannot match the *input* interface of a routed packet in a POSTROUTING hook, so `-i eth3` can't be used above, and the match is done by checking the original IP address source instead.

---

### Addressing a problem with `eth0:0`

While at it, fix the incorrect use of so-called alias interface name, which is a concept that exists only for compatibility with Linux' `ifconfig` command which use has been obsolete for more than 20 years on Linux but is still around. Indeed on Linux `ifconfig` cannot handle more than one IPv4 address on an interface and this workaround has been here to overcome it. `eth0:0` is actually seen by anything else than `ifconfig`, including the kernel, as the address 134.257.10.20/24 set on `eth0` with a label associated `eth0:0`. This secondary address could have been added like this (after the main address was already put in place) with the modern `ip addr` equivalent:

```
ip addr add 134.257.10.20/24 brd + label eth0:0 dev eth0
```

This matters because *iptables* won't match correctly with a rule using `eth0:0`. So it has to be replaced withing *iptables* with a check on the interface: `eth0` plus a check on the IP address in the same rule.

So if the port 80 is intended to reach 192.168.1.10:80 only for the first public IP address and not both, replace:

> ```
> -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10:80
> ```

with:

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 134.257.10.10 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10:80
```

If it's for both addresses, then the initial rule is ok.

But for sure the rule for port 25 should be rewritten like this:

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 134.257.10.20 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.3.33:25
```

The match has to be done on the actual interface (`eth0`) *and* the address, because that's what `eth0:0` is: the address and not an interface.

The final ruleset becomes then (mind the bogus 257 of course):

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -d 134.257.10.10/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10:80
-A PREROUTING -d 134.257.10.20/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.3.33:25
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.3.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 134.257.10.20
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```